# Parser for OCaml

Tags: parsing, types, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, typechecking

Can anyone recommend me an open-source full OCaml parser?

Essentially, I would like to implement my own type-checker for OCaml. Ideally, the parser is written in OCaml. I would just use it to get the AST of the input program. (it is probably too much to ask for the initial typing environment pre-filled with standard library function signatures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `compiler-lib` that is distributed with OCaml under [QPL license](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/license.en.html). It has everything needed to create your own compiler (and even has [some documentation](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/compiler-libs-hack)). `compiler-lib` is essentially a compiler shipped as library.

Otherwise, you can use camlp4 to get the parsetree, but then you need to reimplement everything else from scratch. But at this case you're not restricted with QPL.

Comment: It is actually sort-of-documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/camlspotter/compiler-libs-hack).

Comment: Note that the compiler-libs are distributed under the quite restrictive Q public license whereas camlp4 is LGPL.

Comment: @PatJ, this is a very good point, I didn't know this. Actually, looks like that many projects, that use this library don't know either...

Comment: Could you guys, if it is not too much to ask, just briefly describe what makes this license so restrictive? It might be a little bit off-topic, but it is related to the opening question and people, such as myself, could benefit from it.

Comment: it like GPL, if you distribute your program, than you need to distribute it under QPL too, with sources opened. If you don't make it available to public, then you don't need to bother.

Answer (score 2):

> it is probably too much to ask for the initial typing environment pre-filled with standard library function signatures

It is not! See the files `typing/predef.ml(i)`.

As for the stdlib, just use the same one as the compiler, except for pervasive which uses values from `Predef`, the rest is normal OCaml code without any special cases (except bootstraping, obviously).